# Capistrano deployment error - "config/database.yml: No such file or directory"

Tags: apache, ruby-on-rails-5, rbenv, capistrano3

Not sure what Capistrano is trying to do or what's wrong. I have already set the file and folder permission on my server with user "deploy4" and all the necessary things as mention in here:

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/apache/automating_app_updates/ruby/#setting-up-a-basic-directory-structure

I have tried all other workarounds, but nothing works, i have also tried the same with moving my web dir into the deploy4 home instead of the server "/var/www/", and still the same error happens. i have also `.gitignore` the database and secrets.yml files too.

Same issue applies for `secrets.yml` file

Rails: 5.0.0.1, Ruby: 2.3.1, Capistrano: 3.6.1

**Capistrano Log:**

```
**********@**********:~/Documents/**********/group4$ cap production deploy --trace
** Invoke production (first_time)
** Execute production
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
** Invoke rbenv:validate (first_time)
** Invoke rbenv:install (first_time)
** Execute rbenv:install
** Invoke rbenv:install_rbenv (first_time)
** Execute rbenv:install_rbenv
** Invoke rbenv:install_ruby_build (first_time)
** Execute rbenv:install_ruby_build
** Invoke rbenv:install_ruby (first_time)
** Execute rbenv:install_ruby
** Invoke rbenv:install_bundler (first_time)
** Invoke rbenv:map_bins (first_time)
** Invoke passenger:rbenv:hook (first_time)
** Invoke passenger:test_which_passenger (first_time)
** Execute passenger:test_which_passenger
** Execute passenger:rbenv:hook
** Execute rbenv:map_bins
** Execute rbenv:install_bundler
** Execute rbenv:validate
** Invoke rbenv:map_bins 
** Invoke bundler:map_bins (first_time)
** Invoke passenger:bundler:hook (first_time)
** Execute passenger:bundler:hook
** Execute bundler:map_bins
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_rails_env
** Invoke deploy:set_linked_dirs (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_linked_dirs
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env 
** Invoke deploy (first_time)
** Execute deploy
** Invoke deploy:starting (first_time)
** Execute deploy:starting
** Invoke deploy:check (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check
** Invoke git:check (first_time)
** Invoke git:wrapper (first_time)
** Execute git:wrapper
00:00 git:wrapper
      01 mkdir -p /tmp
    ✔ 01 deploy4@********** 0.011s
    ✔ 01 deploy4@********** 0.013s
      Uploading /tmp/git-ssh-group4-production-**********.sh 100.0%
      Uploading /tmp/git-ssh-group4-production-**********.sh 100.0%
      02 chmod 700 /tmp/git-ssh-group4-production-**********.sh
    ✔ 02 deploy4@********** 0.011s
    ✔ 02 deploy4@********** 0.012s
** Execute git:check
00:00 git:check
      01 git ls-remote --heads git@**********.git
      01 7651cd0265b7494eb5b16e47d056e3f9a52795cc   refs/heads/master
      01 7651cd0265b7494eb5b16e47d056e3f9a52795cc   refs/heads/master
    ✔ 01 deploy4@********** 4.835s
    ✔ 01 deploy4@********** 4.836s
** Invoke deploy:check:directories (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check:directories
00:04 deploy:check:directories
      01 mkdir -p /var/www/web/group4/shared /var/www/web/group4/releases
    ✔ 01 deploy4@********** 0.012s
    ✔ 01 deploy4@********** 0.013s
** Invoke deploy:check:linked_dirs (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check:linked_dirs
00:04 deploy:check:linked_dirs
      01 mkdir -p /var/www/web/group4/shared/log /var/www/web/group4/shared/tmp/pids /var/www/web/group4/shared/tmp…
    ✔ 01 deploy4@********** 0.022s
    ✔ 01 deploy4@********** 0.021s
** Invoke deploy:check:make_linked_dirs (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check:make_linked_dirs
00:04 deploy:check:make_linked_dirs
      01 mkdir -p /var/www/web/group4/shared/config
    ✔ 01 deploy4@********** 0.011s
    ✔ 01 deploy4@********** 0.011s
** Invoke deploy:check:linked_files (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check:linked_files
** Invoke deploy:set_previous_revision (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_previous_revision
** Invoke deploy:started (first_time)
** Execute deploy:started
** Invoke secrets_yml:secrets_yml_symlink (first_time)
** Execute secrets_yml:secrets_yml_symlink
** Invoke deploy:updating (first_time)
** Invoke deploy:new_release_path (first_time)
** Execute deploy:new_release_path
** Execute deploy:updating
** Invoke git:create_release (first_time)
** Invoke git:update (first_time)
** Invoke git:clone (first_time)
** Invoke git:wrapper 
** Execute git:clone
00:05 git:clone
      The repository mirror is at /var/www/web/group4/repo
      The repository mirror is at /var/www/web/group4/repo
** Execute git:update
00:05 git:update
      01 git remote update --prune
      01 Fetching origin
      01 Fetching origin
    ✔ 01 deploy4@********** 4.824s
    ✔ 01 deploy4@********** 4.821s
** Execute git:create_release
00:09 git:create_release
      01 mkdir -p /var/www/web/group4/releases/20160918214854
    ✔ 01 deploy4@********** 0.012s
      02 git archive master group4 | tar -x --strip-components 1 -f - -C /var/www/web/group4/releases/20160918214854
    ✔ 01 deploy4@********** 0.012s
    ✔ 02 deploy4@********** 0.033s
    ✔ 02 deploy4@********** 0.034s
** Invoke deploy:set_current_revision (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_current_revision
** Invoke git:set_current_revision (first_time)
** Execute git:set_current_revision
00:09 git:set_current_revision
      01 echo "7651cd0265b7494eb5b16e47d056e3f9a52795cc" >> REVISION
    ✔ 01 deploy4@********** 0.011s
    ✔ 01 deploy4@********** 0.012s
** Invoke deploy:symlink:shared (first_time)
** Execute deploy:symlink:shared
** Invoke deploy:symlink:linked_files (first_time)
** Execute deploy:symlink:linked_files
00:09 deploy:symlink:linked_files
      01 mkdir -p /var/www/web/group4/releases/20160918214854/config
    ✔ 01 deploy4@********** 0.011s
    ✔ 01 deploy4@********** 0.014s
      02 rm /var/www/web/group4/releases/20160918214854/config/database.yml
    ✔ 02 deploy4@********** 0.011s
      03 ln -s /var/www/web/group4/shared/config/database.yml /var/www/web/group4/releases/20160918214854/config/da…
      02 rm: cannot remove '/var/www/web/group4/releases/20160918214854/config/database.yml': No such file or direc…
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy4@**********: rm exit status: 1
rm stdout: Nothing written
rm stderr: rm: cannot remove '/var/www/web/group4/releases/20160918214854/config/database.yml': No such file or directory
/home/**********/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.3/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute'
/home/**********/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.3/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
SSHKit::Command::Failed: rm exit status: 1
rm stdout: Nothing written
rm stderr: rm: cannot remove '/var/www/web/group4/releases/20160918214854/config/database.yml': No such file or directory
/home/**********/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.3/lib/sshkit/command.rb:100:in `exit_status='
/home/**********/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.3/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:148:in `execute_command'
/home/**********/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.3/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
/home/**********/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.3/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `tap'
/home/**********/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.3/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `create_command_and_execute'
/home/**********/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.3/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:74:in `execute'
/home/**********/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/capistrano-3.6.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/deploy.rake:143:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/**********/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/capistrano-3.6.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/deploy.rake:139:in `each'
/home/**********/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/capistrano-3.6.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/deploy.rake:139:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/**********/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.3/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `instance_exec'
/home/**********/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.3/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `run'
/home/**********/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.3/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => deploy:symlink:linked_files
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as deploy4@**********: rm exit status: 1
rm stdout: Nothing written
rm stderr: rm: cannot remove '/var/www/web/group4/releases/20160918214854/config/database.yml': No such file or directory
** Invoke deploy:failed (first_time)
** Execute deploy:failed

** DEPLOY FAILED
** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 lines:

 DEBUG [6bf2cf17] Command: [ -L /var/www/web/group4/releases/20160918214854/config/database.yml ]
 INFO [ce01eb8c] Finished in 0.014 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [1aa31b6f] Running [ -L /var/www/web/group4/releases/20160918214854/config/database.yml ] as deploy4@**********
 DEBUG [1aa31b6f] Command: [ -L /var/www/web/group4/releases/20160918214854/config/database.yml ]
 DEBUG [6bf2cf17] Finished in 0.007 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [d065dc4b] Running [ -f /var/www/web/group4/releases/20160918214854/config/database.yml ] as deploy4@**********
 DEBUG [d065dc4b] Command: [ -f /var/www/web/group4/releases/20160918214854/config/database.yml ]
 DEBUG [1aa31b6f] Finished in 0.007 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [a8a079de] Running [ -f /var/www/web/group4/releases/20160918214854/config/database.yml ] as deploy4@**********
 DEBUG [a8a079de] Command: [ -f /var/www/web/group4/releases/20160918214854/config/database.yml ]
 DEBUG [d065dc4b] Finished in 0.007 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [c01dbafb] Running /usr/bin/env rm /var/www/web/group4/releases/20160918214854/config/database.yml as deploy4@**********
 DEBUG [c01dbafb] Command: ( export BAZOOKA_USER="**********" http_proxy="**********" https_proxy="**********" ftp_proxy="**********" rsync_proxy="**********" no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com" HTTP_PROXY="" HTTPS_PROXY="" FTP_PROXY="" RSYNC_PROXY="" NO_PROXY="" RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" ; /usr/bin/env rm /var/www/web/group4/releases/20160918214854/config/database.yml )
 DEBUG [a8a079de] Finished in 0.007 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [4c6e0f98] Running /usr/bin/env rm /var/www/web/group4/releases/20160918214854/config/database.yml as deploy4@**********
 DEBUG [4c6e0f98] Command: ( export BAZOOKA_USER="**********" http_proxy="**********" https_proxy="**********" ftp_proxy="**********" rsync_proxy="**********" no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com" HTTP_PROXY="" HTTPS_PROXY="" FTP_PROXY="" RSYNC_PROXY="" NO_PROXY="" RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" ; /usr/bin/env rm /var/www/web/group4/releases/20160918214854/config/database.yml )
 INFO [c01dbafb] Finished in 0.011 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [67264213] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /var/www/web/group4/shared/config/database.yml /var/www/web/group4/releases/20160918214854/config/database.yml as deploy4@**********
 DEBUG [67264213] Command: ( export BAZOOKA_USER="**********" http_proxy="**********" https_proxy="**********" ftp_proxy="**********" rsync_proxy="**********" no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com" HTTP_PROXY="" HTTPS_PROXY="" FTP_PROXY="" RSYNC_PROXY="" NO_PROXY="" RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" ; /usr/bin/env ln -s /var/www/web/group4/shared/config/database.yml /var/www/web/group4/releases/20160918214854/config/database.yml )
 DEBUG [4c6e0f98]   rm: cannot remove '/var/www/web/group4/releases/20160918214854/config/database.yml': No such file or directory
```

**config/deploy.rb file:**

```
# Config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock '3.6.1'

#Set app details
set :application, 'group4'
set :repo_url, 'git@**********'

#For restarting Apache
set :passenger_restart_with_touch, true

# Default branch is :master
# ask :branch, `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp
set :stages,['production']
set :default_stage, 'production'
set :user, 'deploy4'
set :branch, 'master'

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name
set :deploy_to, '/var/www/web/group4'

# Default value for :scm is :git
set :scm, :git

#Set Ruby versions
set :rbenv_type, :user
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.3.1'
set :repo_tree, 'group4'

# Default value for :format is :airbrussh.
# set :format, :airbrussh

# You can configure the Airbrussh format using :format_options.
# These are the defaults.
# set :format_options, command_output: true, log_file: 'log/capistrano.log', color: :auto, truncate: :auto

# Default value for :pty is false
# set :pty, true

# Default value for :linked_files is []
#append :linked_files, 'config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml'
set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml')

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
#append :linked_dirs, 'log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'public/system'
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system')

# Default value for default_env is {}
# set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
set :keep_releases, 5
```

**config/deploy/production.rb file:**

```
# Role-based syntax
role :app, %w{deploy4@**********}
role :web, %w{deploy4@**********}
role :db,  %w{deploy4@**********}, :primary => true

# Configurations
set :branch, 'master'
set :rails_env, "production"
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/web/group4"

set :default_env,{
  'BAZOOKA_USER' => ENV['BAZOOKA_USER'],

  "http_proxy" => "**********",
  "https_proxy" => "**********",
  "ftp_proxy" => "**********",
  "rsync_proxy" => "**********",
  "no_proxy" => "localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com",

  "HTTP_PROXY" => $http_proxy,
  "HTTPS_PROXY" => $https_proxy,
  "FTP_PROXY" => $ftp_proxy,
  "RSYNC_PROXY" => $rsync_proxy,
  "NO_PROXY" => $no_proxy
}

# Custom SSH Options
server '**********',
  user: 'deploy4',
  roles: %w{web app db},
  ssh_options: {
    user: 'deploy4',
    keys: %w(/home/**********/.ssh/id_rsa),
    forward_agent: true,
    auth_methods: %w(publickey password),
    password: '**********'
}
```

[at /var/www/web/group4/shared/config folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGTnE.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've usually seen this in one of two situations:

1. Does `/var/www/web/group4/shared/config/database.yml` exist on your server?
2. Is `/var/www/web/group4/shared/config/database.yml` a symlink to a file which doesn't exist (or a relative symlink)?

Comment: yes for question 1 but not sure about question 2. image on main post.